# Screenshot of gui, choose where to save question

Tags: java

I have a program that takes a screenshot of my gui. It automatically saves the .gif file to the eclipse project directory. What I would like is to have it asking a user where to save the image.  Basically so the user can browse the file directory and choose the directory.
Here's the code I have:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
try{
       String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Save file", 
null, 1);

       if (!fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif")){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: file name must end with \".gif\".",
           null, 1);
       }
       else{             
         BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panel2.getSize().width, 
           panel2.getSize().height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
         panel2.paint(image.createGraphics());
         ImageIO.write(image, "gif", new File(fileName));
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Screen captured successfully.",
null, 1);
       }
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: Fix `catch(Exception e){}` first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a file chooser dialog instead of a JOptionPane. Here is a link for the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Example:
First of all you have to declare JFileChooser object in your class and initialize it.

```
public Class FileChooserExample{
   JFileChooser fc;
   FileChooserExample(...){
      fc = new JFileChooser();// as a parameter you can put path to initial directory to open
      ...
   }
```

Now create another method:

```
private String getWhereToSave(){
    int retVal = fc.showSaveDialog(..);
    if(retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method returns to you the absolute path which user selected. `retVal` indicates which button was pressed (Save or Cancel). And if it was pressed Save then you handle the selected file.

Then you have this method you can incorporate this with your code. Instead of this line:

```
String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Save file", null, 1);
```

Write:

```
String fileName = getWhereToSave();
```

Comment: So I've been looking at FileChooser. I still not sure how to exactly use it. JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(" "); int result = fc.showSaveDialog(this); From what I understood you can user result for CANCEL or APPROVE option.. When I tried to incorporate into my code the directory pops up but it doesnt save my screenshot to the specified directory. I'm also not sure what to pass to ImageIO.write(); thanks for any help

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to find a way to incorporate that line with FileChooser but with no luck. I will try this code to see if it works. Will let you know how it goes!

Comment: for this line [ImageIO.write(image, "gif", fileName);]  I get the following error message "The method write(RenderedImage, String, ImageOutputStream) in the type ImageIO is not applicable for the arguments (BufferedImage, String, String)"

Comment: That's because you are passing as a parameter String value, where method write accepts ImageOutputStream. On your first post it's ok new ImageIO.write(image, "gif", new File(fileName)); Or you can modify method getWhereToSave to return file object instead of a String value where to save.